# Ways to convert ISO 8859-X to UNICODE

Tags: c++, unicode, iso

What are the options for converting ISO 8859-X to UNICODE in C++? By UNICODE I mean UNICODE code points betwen 0 and 65,535 since all ISO 8859-X are character sets which occupy that range.

The most obvious would be to get the mappings tables (http://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/ISO8859/8859-7.TXT) and make a parser for it. But I suppose there are some libraries for this (I have found none)?

I know there is a trivial code for ISO-8859-1 conversion, but let's ignore it since it works with this particular ISO encoding only.

Can you share what the options are? Possibly which pros/cons of each option?

*Personally, I would prefer something lightweight, since I need only the one way conversion and ISO only not a full UNICODE support.*

Comment: Since there's no algorithm, the choices are either tables or a library wrapping those tables. I would call it a resource request, but this isn't subjective. There are official tables. But since those tables are already mentioned, I'm wondering what the real question is.

Comment: I was wondering if there are some sort of libraries for this. Or maybe some functions in the standard C++ library for this? I just wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel if not needed so I'm asking :)

Comment: Have a look at Boost.Locale.

Comment: The range for these outdated ISO 8859 code pages is from 0 to 255. Range for Unicode code point exceeds 65,535. Is this for Windows? Give example of source data.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Yes, Unicode has more than 65535 codepoints.  The **encoded bytes** used by ISO-8859-X are in the 0-255 range and the **codepoints** they represent are within the 0-65535 range, as ISO-8859-X encodings generally predate UTF-16 (or were published around the same time). Though, [codepage 874](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-11#Code_page_874), which is a variation of ISO-8859-11, does have 4 single-byte values that represent multi-codepoint sequences (specifically, `0xDB = U+0E49 U+FE00`, `0xDC = U+0E4A U+FE00`, `0xDD = U+0E4B U+FE00`, and `0xDE = U+0E4C U+FE00`).

Comment: @RemyLebeau you are right. I guess that's what the asker meant to say also, but you can't fit that in a short sentence!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dedicated Unicode conversion library like [ICONV](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) or [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

However, if all you need is conversion from ISO-8859-X to Unicode, not the other way around, and no other charsets, then you could simply declare a static `wchar_t[16][256]` array containing the appropriate Unicode codepoints. There are only 16 ISO-8859 charsets defined (well, a few more if you count variants), with up to 256 values each. Then you can loop through your input string using its characters as indexes into the array.

Comment: `wchar_t` is very platform dependent, use `char16_t` or `char32_t` instead.